# FaultCode.CreateReceiverFaultCode / FaultCode.CreateSenderFaultCode inconsistency

Tags: wcf, soap

If [FaultCode.CreateReceiverFaultCode(FaultCode subCode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195507(v=vs.110).aspx) is called with a null argument, an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown.

If [FaultCode.CreateSenderFaultCode(FaultCode subCode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195509(v=vs.110).aspx) is called with a null argument, no exception is thrown.

The linked MSDN documentation for these methods suggests that both will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the `subCode` argument is null.

What is the reason for this apparently inconsistent behaviour?

The [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/FaultCode.cs) doesn't have any comments that throw light on this.